# Give an example of a measure such that sine preserves this measure

Tags: measure-theory, trigonometry, dynamical-systems

Define $T:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ by $T(x) = \sin\pi x.$ Is there an example of a measure $\mu$ such that $([-1,1], \mathcal B, \mu, T),$ where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, is a measure-preserving dynamical system?

Progress so far: Define $g(x) = \mu([0, x)),$ for $0 < x \le 1.$ Then

\begin{align*}
g(x) &= \mu([0,x)) = \mu\big(T^{-1}[0,x)\big) \\
&=\mu\big([0,\pi^{-1}\sin^{-1}x)\cup[1-\pi^{-1}\sin^{-1}x,1)\big)\\
&=g(\pi^{-1}\sin^{-1}x) + \mu([0,1))-\mu\big([0,1-\sin^{-1}x)\big)\\
&=g(\pi^{-1}\sin^{-1}x) + g(1) - g(1-\pi^{-1}\sin^{-1}x),
\end{align*}

where $\sin^{-1}:[-1,1]\to[-\pi/2,\pi/2].$

We can assume that $g(1)=1/2.$ Solving this functional equation for $g$ is sufficient to determine $\mu.$ I have tried to use some results from measure theory to do this (e.g. part (ii) of theorem 2.2 [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj64ePWzPjWAhXExVQKHYuqCn8QFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783540231219-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-137971-p35030716&usg=AOvVaw1izgtjW1J2KLoi5m_ohUzw)), to no success.

It is not true that $g(\pi^{-1}\sin^{-1}x)=g(1) - g(1-\pi^{-1}\sin^{-1}x).$

I also know that for a half period, $T(x)=\sin\pi x/2,$ no such measure exists.